# Do I need to create more activites?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, onitemclicklistener

I made a app about a City in India Called "Chennai". It is a tour guide app, in that I have four fragments for different type of tourist places and other categories.

[I have attached a screenshot .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K1WU.png)

So in that app if I wanted to provide more details of that location when a user clicks the List View Item **(in a separate screen)** ,Do I need to create a new activity and Layout for each List Item.

Is there any shorter way?

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant as a resource to have others write code for you. If you try something in an attempt to shorten your code, and then run into a bug in regards to that attempt, StackOverflow would then be the place to ask about that bug.

Comment: Could be better to start a new activity. If tap on list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , if you are fetching data from database 
Create only one activity and pass data like "id" through intent and receive data in that activity and check data for particular "id"